# What does this card mean in Everdell?

Tags: untagged

This card confuses me.  It's from the second edition of Everdell.

[image]
What does it mean?  It could be...

1. Draw two meadow cards.  Play one of them for one resource less than it would normally cost.
2. Draw two meadow cards.  Play one of them for one resource (likely less than the original cost of playing that item).
3. Draw two meadow cards.  Play one and gain a free resource.  This seems unlikely, but isn't that what paying -1 resources means?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Option 1 is correct.

The designer James Wilson has clarified this on a [BGG Forum Post](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2028539/draw-2-meadow-cards-and-play-1-1-any)

He clarified the following was correct (copy and pasted from the post)

> "draw two Meadow cards, and then play one of those cards you just
> drew with a discount of 1 on any resource."